# Queries sent to the database written in mysql do not return a response

Tags: dart

When I send a query code to a database written in mysql, it returns an empty response. But when I use the Create table query, a new table is being added to the database, and all other query operators are not responding. Please help me to solve this problem

The code i tried

```
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

void main() async {
  final settings = ConnectionSettings(
    host: '10.0.2.2',
    port: 3307,
    user: 'root',
    password: '#alisher_2001\$',
    db: 'mbsupermarket',
  );

  final conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
  var searchId = 4;
  var results = await conn.query('SELECT filial_nomi FROM mbsupermarket.filial WHERE id_supermarket = ?',
      [searchId]);

  for (var row in results) {
    print(row[0]);
  }
  
  await conn.close();
}
```

[image: The following error occurred in the code I wrote]

Comment: Hey! Did you tried running MySQL query in MySQL CLI directly? Does it return correct response ?

Comment: is returning an image error.

Comment: what can i do ?

Comment: I meant without relying on Dart. Query it directly on MySQL CLI or the web server which you're using. If its returning error, post that message as well.

Comment: Please upload your error message as text, not as an image.

Comment: I could not find a solution to this problem. but I rewrote my database in postgresql and was able to easily link it to my flutter app using the postgres:^2.6.1 package. Thanks to everyone who helped me :)